# Extract and Convert NSData from BLE to Float in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, type-conversion, nsdata

I'm developing an IOS App that handles a BlueTooth SensorTag.
That SensorTag is based on the TI BLE SensorTag, but we had some of the Sensors removed.

In the sourcecode of the original IOS App from TI the XYZ-Values are calculated like follows
with KXTJ9_RANGE defined as 1.0 in my implementation and KXTJ9 is the Accelerometer built on the SensorTag

```
+(float) calcXValue:(NSData *)data {
  char scratchVal[data.length];
  [data getBytes:&scratchVal length:3];
  return ((scratchVal[0] * 1.0) / (64 / KXTJ9_RANGE));
}
```

The data comes as hexadecimal like "fe850d" and by the method will be cut in 3 parts.
Now i'm trying to convert this method to swift, but i get the wrong numbers back

e.g. `fe` should return something around `0.02` what the objective C Code does

My Swift Code so far

```
class Sensor: NSObject {
  let Range: Float = 1.0
  var data: NSData
  var bytes: [Byte] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00]

  init(data: NSData) {
    self.data = data
    data.getBytes(&bytes, length: data.length)
  }

  func calcXValue()->Float {
    return ((Float(bytes[0]) * 1.0) / (64.0 / Range))
  }
...
}
```

I believe problem must lie around my `Float(bytes[0])` because that makes `254` out of `fe` whereas `scratchVal[0]` in ObjectiveC is around 64

But my main problem is, i was all new with IOS programming when i had to begin with this project, so i chose to use Swift to learn and code the app with it.

Right now i use the original Objective C Code from TI to use with our SensorTag, but i would prefer using Swift for every part in the App.

Comment: `char` is a *signed* quantity whereas `Byte` is *unsigned*. Try using an `[Int8]` array instead.

Comment: Thanks, thats what made the difference =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all current iOS and OS X platforms, `char` is a *signed* quantity,
so that the input `fe` is treated as a negative number.

`Byte` on the other hand is an alias for `UInt8` which is *unsigned*.
Use `[Int8]` array instead to get the same behaviour as in your Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the BLE device Endianness, in relation to your device Endianness.
[wiki on Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

To keep it simple you need to check which does two method

```
NSData *data4 = [completeData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
int value = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(*(int*)([data4 bytes]));
```

or

```
NSData *data4 = [completeData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
int value = CFSwapInt32LittleToHost(*(int*)([data4 bytes]));
```

And check which one make more sense when you parse the data.